# Notification when laptop is switch on (boot)

Tags: notifications, reboot

I need to know, is that possible to get a notification through email whenever my laptop is switched on or is connected to internet ?

An alternative is to get notification when set service 'Starts' on system boot.

Need C# code for this service.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a web site somewhere and access to the log files, install `wget` or `curl` and then run this command:

```
wget -q http://your.site.com/MyLaptopIsConnected
```

Just search the error logs for this string to see when your laptop came online. Put the command in a BAT/CMD file and tell Windows to run it once the computer starts with the scheduler.